# Proving a conditional by assuming the antecedent

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

My question is about proving the conditional statement true in propositional logic or math. In proving conditionsal statements, a lot of proofs assume the antecedent is true and then show that the consequent must be true from that.

Let's say the conditional is: If P, then Q. What does it mean in the truth table, for example, when P is true and Q is true. On the wiki page Conditional Proof it says "Thus, the goal of a conditional proof is to demonstrate that if the CPA [conditional proof assumption] were true, then the desired conclusion necessarily follows. The validity of a conditional proof does not require that the CPA [conditional proof assumption] to be true, only that if it were true it would lead to the consequent." So we assume P is true- but it potentially might not be- to prove the conditional is true. And the conditional is still true even when P turns out to be false. **So when we are using truth tables to define the conditional statement "If P, then Q", what does it mean where it says P is true? We don't know that P is true we just assumed it.**

I guess I assumed that it was shown that P is a true proposition and Q is a true proposition, therefore "If P, then Q" is a true proposition.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you are asking about proving $Q$ or about proving "if $P$ then $Q$".

Comment: What does truth value of P mean in proving the conditional. It can't mean P is a true proposition because we just assumed P was true. We didn't prove it true. In fact it can be a false proposition, but we can still assume it's true in proving "If P, then Q" is a true proposition. So what does it mean when P has a true value in the truth table?

Comment: Let $P$ be "$x>3$". Let $Q$ be "$x>2$". From $P$, we can deduce $Q$, so it is true that "if $P$, then $Q$". This makes no assumption about the truth of $P$. If $x$ turns out to be $2.5$, or $1$, it is still true that "if $P$, then $Q$", even though $P$ happens to be false in these cases.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are getting at, but if you know only that P is false and that P implies Q, you cannot infer anything about the truth value of Q, i.e. whether Q is true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > **So when we are using truth tables to define the conditional statement "If P, then Q", what does it mean where it says P is
   > true?**
   >
   > **We don't know that P is true we just assumed it.**

   As you pointed out, the truth table for the logical
   operator/connective $\to$ is providing its definition. Notice that this
   definition doesn't consider the interpretation (assigned meaning) of
   the antecedent and consequent. Think of $\to$ as a truth-function
   (like any mathematical function), which returns a single,
   clearly-defined output (either T or F) when given any allowable
   input (which here is any of its four possible input combinations).

   This definition is neutral to the truth value of $P;$ we never had
   to assume that $P$ is true.
2. > In proving conditional statements, a lot of proofs assume the
   > antecedent is true and then show that the consequent must be true from
   > that.
   >
   > I guess I assumed that it was shown that P is a true proposition and Q
   > is a true proposition, therefore "If P, then Q" is a true proposition.

   Consider the following symbolisation key:
    $\quad P_1:$ Pigs are
   animals.
    $\quad P_2:$ Pigs are canines.
    $\quad Q_1:$
   Quadrants contain right angles.
    $\quad Q_2:$ Quadrants contain
   obtuse angles.

   Then, for each interpretation (choice of $P_i$ and $Q_j$), the
   statement $P_i\to Q_j$ has a definite truth value.

   If, in a particular interpretation, it is known in advance that
   $P_i\to Q_j$ *is* a true statement, then $Q$ is true under the
   assumption/hypothesis that $P$ is true.
3. When making logical arguments (e.g., in Mathematics), $P$ is not an
   atomic statement like the above, but actually a conjunction of premises each of which is a quantified compound statement. Similarly for $Q.$

   When, under a theory's axioms, the statement $P\to Q$ is logically
   true (i.e., true regardless of interpretation), then we call the
   statement a **theorem**. An example of a **valid argument** is $\text“P$ is true, and $P\to Q$ is a theorem; therefore $Q$ is true”.